# TikZ/pgfplots - are there any problems related to externalized figures used on Linux and Windows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, tikz-external

I share a document between Win 7 and Xubuntu 13.10. I just updated my local git repo on my Xubuntu 13.10 installation.

I then continued editing in a TikZ figure (not only its style definitions!) but I can't seem to get it updated (despite [tweaking TeXstudio's settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170291/tikz-wont-let-me-externalize-and-halts-on-error)).

I always have to delete the graphic I want changed before a compile. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Upgrade to pgf 3.0.0 . This will automatically detect changes to the tikz figure.