# tikzexternalize in TeXMaker doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker, tikz-external, shell-escape

I'm having some troubles while compiling my thesis with the tikz externalize feature in Texmaker. I created the user command:

```
"D:/laTex/texlive2014/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

I'm using this in my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}    %if I comment this
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]   %and this the process goes fine
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\begin{document}
\today
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
]
% use TeX as calculator:
\addplot {x^2 - x +4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but anyways it doesn't works.

I receive this in the error windows:

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interact
ion=batchmode -jobname "tikz/minexample-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{mine
xample}\input{minexample}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/minexa
mple-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you h
ave enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Somet
imes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command s
imply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/minexample-figure0.log'. If 
you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

but there is no log file in the folder I already created.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did I make any error? sorry, my english isn't so good.

Comment: No errors, it's just that in this site there is no need to sign your questions or to explicitly thank other users (except for upvoting and accepting answers). Moreover, if you could provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` you would avoid the setup phase for the users willing to help. `;)`

Comment: I succeded using texworks but not TexStudio. I don't know where is the problem .. but I would like to continue using it! Does not anyone know the solution?

Comment: If the topic is actually about TeXStudio, please edit its title. [This simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?&q=texstudio+externalize+tikz) should list [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170291/tikz-wont-let-me-externalize-and-halts-on-error) in its first 5 results.

Comment: I was using texmaker but I read a topic where a user was telling that texmaker is outdate and now the project goes under texstudio. So I tried texstudio too, that is about the same and still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the: '\tikzexternalize[optimize=false,prefix=tikz/]' but it's still not working. @henry

Comment: Guys I solved reinstalling texlive, I noticed that typing in the cmd pdflatex.exe it didn't find anything. Now I have it working and the string I wrote in the upper part of the topic is the right one. It works even without the optimize=false.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. You need to check the file `'tikz/minexample-figure0.log'` to find the actual cause for the error. Besides, checking the link I posted might prove helpful.

Comment: I checked the 'tikz/minexample-figure0.log' but no file were generated except for a .md5 file not being helpful. Now I solved as I told in the previous comment. I don't know if I can mark the question as solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to an inability to find pdflatex (or something like that) and was solved by reinstalling the TeX distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved reinstalling texlive, I noticed that typing in the cmd pdflatex.exe it didn't find anything. Now I have it working and the string I wrote in the question is the right one. It works even without the optimize=false.

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```